# Managed Package Named Credential password gone

Tags: managed-package, namedcredentials

I have a managed package with some apex code that makes a callout to a named credential. The named credential uses a username and password. This gets send in a header in the callout request as an authorization header and base64 encoded "username:password".

Testing this in my org works fine but when including the named credential in a managed package and installing to another org, the named credential works but the header comes through with a missing password: "username:*".

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since 2015 you have to add your named credentials again after installation. See
[Release Notes Spring 2015](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_isvforce_packaging_named_credentials.htm)

> After installation from a managed or unmanaged package, the subscriber must reauthenticate to the external system:

- For password authentication, the subscriber must re-enter the password in the named credential definition.

Comment: So this need to be done manually in every org that installs the package? Obviously this isn't suitable for a package distributed publicly on app exchange?

Comment: Nope its not the perfect solution for a managed package. Maybe you can take a look here https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/secure-secret-storage/learn-about-platform-secret-protection

Comment: the link provided byb @utm seemd ot be dead.. 
here is an alternative link which helped me - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/secure-secrets-storage/protect-secrets-using-platform-features

Comment: You can find the information here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_behavior.htm

Section: Named Credentials