# Named Credential Secret Access Key is Not working in a Managed Package

Tags: apex, managed-package, package, namedcredentials

I have created a named Credential that is perfectly working in my org. But the issue is, when I add these named credential is a managed package it does not work unless I update the 'Secret Access Key' field manually with the same key that i am using in the packaging org. Kindly help me resolve the matter

Comment: Hi @hadeg2, welcome to SFSE. Does this answer question? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/316628/4726

Comment: Hi @Raul, Yes I have already gone through this. But I don't want user to manually add anything in named creds instead named creds That i created should be used in the managed package. Is there anyway for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Managed Package Named Credential password gone](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316625/managed-package-named-credential-password-gone)

Comment: It does not answer my question

Comment: Unfortunately it does. You not wanting to admit the answer is correct does not make the answer invalid. You need to rethink your packaging and larger solution architecture.

Comment: maybe I could not properly implemented?

Comment: Now LWC send email button is also not working in managed package too